# calculating Probability of cars being faulty

Tags: probability, combinations

my question is:
In 100 cars research shows 3 to be faulty. If 3 cars are selected at random, what is the probabiity that exactly 2 are faulty.

So here is my working so far. I'm not too good at maths but as far as I have determined:

(1/100 x 2/99 x 3/98) = 1/161700 -  This is the probability of all 3 cars being faulty.

I'm a bit confused so I tried multiplying that answer by 2/99 cause it says 2 are faulty. But that is giving me an 1/8004150 - This number is too big and it's not right according to the answer which is supposed to be 97/53900

I then tried reverse working it and I found by timsing by 2 get me 1/53900. I am currently trying to work backwards, but its not getting anywhere

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Add your efforts to the question in order to prevent downvotes and or closing.

Comment: Sorry about that, i was getting my working together.

Comment: It would be better to write the probability of all three cars being faulty as $\frac{3}{100} \cdot \frac{2}{99} \cdot \frac{1}{98}$ since $3$ of the initial $100$ cars are faulty, $2$ of the remaining $99$ cars are faulty if the first selection is faulty, and $1$ of the remaining $98$ cars are faulty if the first two selections are faulty.

Comment: I don't really follow.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cars one by one an for $i=1,2,3$ let $F_i$ denote the event that the car chosen as number $i$ is faulty. Then the event that exactly $2$ cars will be faulty is:$$E:=(F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3^{\complement})\cup(F_1\cap F_2^{\complement}\cap F_3)\cup(F_1^{\complement}\cap F_2\cap F_3)$$

This is a union of $3$ disjoint sets and we can calculate the probability of e.g. the first like this:$$P(F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3^{\complement})=P(F_1)P(F_2\mid F_1)P(F_3^{\complement}\mid F_1\cap F_2)=\frac3{100}\frac2{99}\frac{97}{98}$$

On a similar way the two others can be calculate and it will appear that we find the same outcome.

Then we find:$$P(E)=3\times\frac3{100}\frac2{99}\frac{97}{98}$$

---

Making use of the theory concerning hypergeometric distribution we find the outcome:$$\frac{\binom32\binom{97}1}{\binom{100}3}$$

Comment: Thanks, how can we incorporate that into the question: None are faulty

Comment: Then the answer is $\frac{\binom30\binom{97}3}{\binom{100}3}$.

Comment: Where does the 97C3 come from? I understand everything else I just don't get where 97C3 came from or 97C1

Comment: If no faulty cars are selected then from the $97$ non-faulty cars $3$ cars are selected. There are exactly $\binom{97}3$ ways to do that.